# Run time error 1004 "Interior.Color"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm programmatically creating Excel workbooks, with a macro associated to a button, this macro is supposed to check if the values entered by the user in the worksheet are correct and to color the cells in green or red depending on the case.

The macro's code is in another Excel workbook and is added to the created workbooks with this code :

```
 With newWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(350, 115, 50, 41.25)
    .Caption = "Vérifier la conformité"
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!check_FCM"
 End With
```

Here is the macro's code part that doesn't work :

```
For i = 0 To col - 1
    If (IsNumeric(Cells(29, i + 2).Value)) Then
        If (Cells(29, i + 2).Value >= Cells(31, i + 2).Value And Cells(29, i + 2).Value <= Cells(32, i + 2)) Then
            Range(Cells(29, i + 2).Address()).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
       Else
            Range(Cells(29, i + 2).Address()).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            isCorrect = False '
        End If '
    End If '
Next i '
```

The problem seems to be coming from the use of "`Interior.Color=RGB(x,y,z)`" because when I remove it I don't get a bug.

Comment: Is the worksheet protected? BTW, you can use: `Cells(29, i + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)` rather than `Range(Cells(29, i + 2).Address()).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)`

Comment: Yes, the sheet is protected and it works fine when I remove the protection, however I need to keep the worksheet protected, how can I the make the macro work ?

Comment: You need to turn off the protection before applying new color and turn it on afterwards. Or you can change the level of protection to allow changing  cells color.

Comment: Either allow formatting when you protect the sheet (assuming the cells you are changing are not locked) or unprotect in the code, change the formatting, then reprotect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **Unprotect** and **Protect** sheet as follow:

```
Sheets("sheetname").Unprotect

For i = 0 To col - 1

    If (IsNumeric(Cells(29, i + 2).Value)) Then

        If (Cells(29, i + 2).Value >= Cells(31, i + 2).Value And Cells(29, i + 2).Value <= Cells(32, i + 2)) Then
            Cells(29, i + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Else
            Cells(29, i + 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            isCorrect = False 
        End If 

    End If 

Next i 

Sheets("sheetname").Protect
```

And also can use **Cells** object to change color. Check it. I made small modification to your code.

Comment: For anyone who is wondering, Mac Excel 2016 seems to absolutely require the unprotect whereas Windows Excel 2013 works with UserInterfaceOnly: True ...